# child Process reply after 10 min to browser api

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I am trying to run a node js child process in the backend which is taking at least 10 min time to complete, and I want to send the response after 10 min. In node js, i have increased the server timeout to 10 min and its fine. But in the browser, it's still a problem. Its saying timeout error after 2 min of waiting.

As I am using axios module from npm, it has the functionality of timeout but that not working.

Could someone help me how to stalled browser for more than 10 min to send the message from the server and then render the UI?

UI Code:
action created code->

```
export const executeFile = (fileName) => {
  return ((dispatch)=>{
    axios.post(`/execute`,{fileName},{timeout:1000000}).then(
      res=> dispatch({
        type:'EXECUTE_FILE',
        payload:res
      })
    ).catch(err=>console.log(err))

  })
  }
```

backend code->

```
app.post('/execute',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.fileName,"aaaaaaaaa");
    // handler_function.deleteFolderRecursive()
    exec('sleep 200 && ls', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err,"here");
    return;
  }
  console.log(stdout,"in here sucess");
    res.send(stdout)
    });
});
```

Comment: each browser has his default timeout . you cant change this.

Comment: Is there no way to do that?

Comment: for firefox you can do it like this https://support.mozilla.org/he/questions/1042479 but notice its will work only for your pc

Comment: You can't "run a child process in the backend". The server and client are two completely separate machines. Just let your server answer with a status message indicating that your computation has been started and do the computation asynchronously. Then after your computation is done you can persist the results for the client to request it. Alternatively you could use websockets for result transmission.

Comment: I didn't get you, why I cant run child process on the backend ? And how to use WebSocket, do you have any reference code to it. That will be a great help.

Comment: An answer to a http request should be immediate. This protocol is not designed to be blocking for a long time. And with "long time" i mean not more that a few seconds maximum. You should let your server spawn an asynchronously running task that does the computation and answer with something like "I got it. Check back for the results later at /results/<yourComputationID>". Or if your establish a websocket connection between the server and the client your can even inform the client that the computation is done. There are plenty of resources to get you started with websockets.

Comment: Thanks, using socket io solved my problem.